# How to change StackView content after the view has loaded?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode8

i have created a new instance of UIstackView in a file called Stages

```
    class Stages: UIStackView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        }

func SetUpStageOne() {
add some views inside a stackview

func SetUpStageTwo() {
add some new views inside a stackview
}
```

I am stuck trying to figure out how i can get the StackView to appear at Run-time like this

```
        class Stages: UIStackView {

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

           if score == 0 {
           SetUpStageOne()
    }
           if score == 1 {
           SetUpStageTwo()
        }

        required init(coder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: coder)
           if score == 0 {
           SetUpStageOne()
    }
           if score == 1 {
           SetUpStageTwo()
        }

   }

    func SetUpStageOne() {
    add some views inside a stackview

    func SetUpStageTwo() {
    add some new views inside a stackview
    }
```

i can get the first StackView to appear, when the score == 0
but thoughout the game, i want to update the stackview so that the second stackview appear when the score == 1, but that dosnt happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using self.setNeedsLayout() at the end of each setupstage method. This will adjust the layout of a view's subviews. self.setNeedsDisplay() will not work as it resets the view if you have overridden the draw(_ rect) function.

Comment: @user3211359 I have updated my answer. Hopefully, it works this time.